# Optimizing reverse movmskb code

Tags: assembly

I have some code that performs (nearly) the opposite function of a pmovmskb.

It takes as input a 16-bit bitfield and expands it into 2 xmm registers.
(I'm limited to working with AVX1 code).

The code I've come up with is:

```
const SliverToSliceMask = 0x0001-0002-0004-0008-0010-0020-0040-0080

movdqu xmm14,[rip+SliverToSliceMask]    ;xmm14 = mask to isolate bits 0..7
movdqa xmm15,xmm14                      ;xmm15 = mask
pslldq xmm15,1                          ;convert mask from bit 0..7 to bit 8..15
and edx,r8d                             ;combine the two slivers
  //Now expand the sliver into a slice
movd xmm0, edx              ;xmm0 = sliver
pshuflw xmm0,xmm0,$00       ;Paste the sliver 4 times (expanding it to 8 bytes).
pshufd xmm0, xmm0, $50     ;Paste the sliver 2 more times (expanding it to 16 bytes)
movdqa xmm1,xmm0           ;make a copy,expanding it to 32 bytes (in 2 regs)
//now xmm0 and xmm1 are filled with 16 copies of the input sliver, mask out the bit
//that is intended per word
pand xmm0,xmm14             ;mask off the words for bit 0..7
pand xmm1,xmm15             ;mask off the words for bit 8..15
pcmpeqw xmm0,xmm14          ;set 1's to $FFFF and 0's to 0
pcmpeqw xmm1,xmm15          ;Thus expanding the sliver (1 bit per outer sliver) 
                            ;to a slice (16 bits per sliver)
```

Is there a way to optimize this code. I would esp. like to get rid of the memory access to fetch the mask.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is SSE but not AVX, so here is the SSE version to generate the mask. The second part is same as yours. I modified it from my other code and NEVER tested:

```
; generate the bit mask
pcmpeqd         xmm15, xmm15  ; FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF FFFFFFFF
psrlq           xmm15, 63     ; 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000001
movdqa          xmm14, xmm15  ;
psllq           xmm14, 17     ; 00000000 00020000 00000000 00020000
por             xmm15, xmm14  ; 00000000 00020001 00000000 00020001
movdqa          xmm14, xmm15
psllq           xmm14, 34     ; 00080004 00000000 00080004 00000000
por             xmm15, xmm14  ; 00080004 00020001 00080004 00020001
movdqa          xmm14, xmm15
psllq           xmm14, 4      ; 00800040 00200010 00800040 00200010
punpcklqdq      xmm15, xmm14  ; 00800040 00200010 00080004 00020001

; generate the second bit mask
movdqa          xmm15, xmm14
psllw           xmm15, 8      ; 80004000 20001000 08000400 02000100

; load and broadcast DX
movd            xmm0, edx     ; xmm0 = sliver
pshuflw         xmm0, xmm0, 0 ; xmm0 = sliver * 4
pshufd          xmm0, xmm0, 0 ; xmm0 = sliver * 8
movdqa          xmm1, xmm0

; apply the mask
pand            xmm0, xmm14   ; apply mask
pand            xmm1, xmm15   ; apply mask
pcmpeqw         xmm0,xmm14    ; mask to FFFF
pcmpeqw         xmm1,xmm15    ; mask to FFFF
```

If you are using AVX, you can omit those `movdqa` and the code will look better. The SSE version is long and I am not sure its better than a simple memory read, as your did.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] it to explain your reasoning (how your solution works and how it improves upon the original) so that everyone can learn from your thought process.